# Wildfly default value for blocking-timeout-wait-millis

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-22

I have searched the wildfly documentation but didn't find any information on the default value of a datasource [blocking-timeout-wait-millis](https://%20https://docs.wildfly.org/22/wildscribe/deployment/subsystem/datasources/data-source/index.html#attr-blocking-timeout-wait-millis). So if the element is not specified in the configuration what default value does it get? (since the name contain 'millis' at least it is clear what the unit is) I also checked the value via jmx however the field is just empty...

Comment: I just watched a live server and there the "MaxWaitTime" is 29898 which could indicate that the default is 30.000ms.

Comment: The only similar reference I could find was [in IronJacamar](https://github.com/ironjacamar/ironjacamar/blob/174a5125ae9e358037065d9d5191d8a16a7141ea/core/api/src/main/java/org/jboss/jca/core/api/connectionmanager/pool/PoolConfiguration.java#L110), so you may be correct with 30000 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it in the wildfly [datasource schemas](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/main/connector/src/main/resources/schema/wildfly-datasources_7_0.xsd):

```
<xs:complexType name="timeoutType">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="blocking-timeout-millis" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>
        <![CDATA[[
          The blocking-timeout-millis element indicates the maximum time in
          milliseconds to block while waiting for a connection before throwing an exception.
          Note that this blocks only while waiting for a permit for a connection, and
          will never throw an exception if creating a new connection takes an inordinately
          long time. The default is 30000 (30 seconds).
         ]]>
      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
...
```